# Recomendations for Light Summary Algorithm on ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, cryptojs

I'm trying to upload big texts to my database, on this case cant be text files because are generated dynamically on each use of the app. And this can create like hundreds of files if I use that method.

The main problem is that MySQL has a maximum number of characters quantity allowed.

I saw that some people recommend MD5 or SHA to reduce big text to a short string. But this only works in one way.

Is there another way to do this, or with other Light Summary Algorithm?